# Ruby TDD Plus Coding: Dealing with Booleans

Tags: ruby

## TDD

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.2'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/pride'
require_relative 'kid'

class KidTest < Minitest::Test

 def test_kid_has_not_eaten_sugar
 
  kid = Kid.new
  assert_equal 0, kid.grams_of_sugar_eaten
 end

 def test_kid_gets_5_grams_from_eating_candy

  kid = Kid.new
  kid.eat_candy
  assert_equal 5, kid.grams_of_sugar_eaten

  5.times { kid.eat_candy }
  assert_equal 30, kid.grams_of_sugar_eaten
 end

 def test_kid_is_not_hyperactive

  kid = Kid.new
  refute kid.hyperactive?
 end

 def test_kid_is_hyperactive_after_60_grams_of_sugar

  kid = Kid.new
  11.times { kid.eat_candy }
  refute kid.hyperactive?, "Not hyperactive yet..."
  kid.eat_candy
  assert kid.hyperactive?, "OK, now the kid is hyperactive."
 end
end
```

## CODE

```
 class Kid
  attr_reader :grams_of_sugar_eaten

  def initialize
   @grams_of_sugar_eaten = 0
  end

  def eat_candy(grams = 5)
   @grams_of_sugar_eaten += grams
  end

  def hyperactive?
    @grams_of_sugar_eaten >= 60
  end
 end
```

How can I go about to make the test pass for the last test?
The kid is initially not hyperactive and now after eating candy, he is hyperactive.

I have defined a method hyperactive? and refuted that the kid is hyperactive by stating that it is false, but how do I then go about keeping that statement and then addressing that the kid is hyperactive after eating candy? Any direction in the right step is greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE*

So, with the help of others, the answer that made sense to me would be the final code written here. All tests pass.

To start, I made a class Kid to address the new instance of Kid being made.

The first test wants to see if the kid has 0 grams_of_sugar_eaten.

I defined the method by initializing gram_of_sugar_eaten as an instance variable and setting that to 0. I made sure to add the attr_reader up top so that it can be accessed throughout the whole file.

Next test wants to see that the kid gets 5 grams_of_sugar_eaten from eating candy.

I defined the method of eat_candy and to address the kid eating 5 grams_of_sugar_eaten, I passed it in as an argument with the variable that I set as grams and assigned that to the Integer of 5.

To address the last part of that test, I have set the instance variable of
grams_of_sugar_eaten plus/equal to grams. This will address whatever increments the grams eaten.

The next test is to see if the kid is not hyperactive. I initially just wrote a hyperactive? method and assigned that to false, then I looked ahead and saw that the next test was asking to see if the kid is not hyperactive even after eating up to 59 grams of sugar.

Once he hits 60 grams of sugar, he becomes hyperactive, so to address this,
instead of a visible if/then statement stating false/true, I simplified it by putting the instance variable of grams_of_sugar_eaten to greater than or equal to 60.

This is pretty much saying the if/then statements implicitly by asking if the 60 is greater than or equal to the grams_of_sugar_eaten, it's true, if it doesn't reach that point, then it's false.

Comment: There are a million ways to implement the internals of `Kid`, `eat_candy` and `hyperactive?`. You need to attempt to solve this yourself and then include all the relevant code here, along with a specific question about where you're stuck. Asking us to implement everything to your specification is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Gotcha, appreciate the input. I guess I solved the first test by refuting that the kid is hyperactive by defining the method hyperactive? and stating that that is false. My issue is that once you refute that initial statement, what direction do I need to go to keep that assertion that it is false initially and then addressing the issue of the kid eating candy and then becoming hyperactive

Comment: You need to implement whatever `eat_candy` does, and then alter the implementation of `hyperactive?` to use whatever you come up with from `eat_candy`. It seems like you probably want to maintain some state about how much candy the `Kid` has eaten and then compare that state with whatever threshold you want to use to determine whether the kid is `hyperactive?`.

Comment: Hm ok, here's the whole snippet of the TDD and code that I have, that might give you a better picture of what I was doing. So I have defined the eat_candy method, I'm assuming I need to add an attr_reader for it and then try working that into how much the kid ate?

Comment: That sounds like the right direction, yes.

Comment: One of the ideas of TDD is to write the simplest code needed to make each test pass and then write another failing test, and then make that test pass etc. So you were right to make a `hyperactive?` that always returns `false` in order to make `test_kid_is_not_hyperactive` pass. However that code is no longer enough to make `test_kid_is_hyperactive_after_60_grams_of_sugar` also pass. So you need to write a `hyperactive?` method that returns different things depending on how much sugar eaten. And you have the value for how much sugar eaten in `@grams_of_sugar_eaten`

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm having a hard time figuring out how to go about doing that, would false unless @grams_of_sugar_eaten > 60 else true make any sense? It doesn't work but am I in the right ballpark?

Comment: Yep, definitely in the right ballpark. Is this a course you're studying? Are there some lessons to give you some guidance?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to learn ruby, there aren't any specific lessons on it, but the expectation is to read about booleans and understand them and then work that into code and writing methods. Any tips to revise what I had to something that makes sense? It's giving me:   1) Failure:
KidTest#test_kid_is_hyperactive_after_60_grams_of_sugar [kid_test.rb:32]:
Not hyperactive yet...

  2) Failure:
KidTest#test_kid_is_not_hyperactive [kid_test.rb:25]:
Expected true to not be truthy.

Comment: Something like this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm or this https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-ruby/lessons/control-flow-in-ruby/ is a good starting point.

Comment: Ok appreciate the help. I'll try to see if I can get it to work

Comment: Cool. Do post another question if you get stuck but try and read some general tutorials on booleans and then ask a specific question when you need help. People will be much more likely to answer when they see what you've already tried and when the question isn't as broad.

Comment: Hm, I've posted two tries at solving it, but both give me an error, am I getting closer or still missing something?

Comment: The second version (where you've used `if @grams_of_sugar_eaten > 60`) is _almost_ there. Looking at the test, if the kid eats sugar 12 times (exactly 60 grams) then that's enough to become hyperactive. So you want to "use greater than or equal to" (`>=`) in place of just "greater than" (`>`).

Comment: ah that would be it. I appreciate you pointing that out. Why is this robot language so hard for me to grasp??

Comment: The question has been edited out of being a question. This should either be closed or reframed as a question with an answer.

Comment: I agree, I have updated the comments about what has happened. Thanks for letting me know.